# Why are the values showing up as column headers when I try to create a text table in Tableau?

Tags: datatable, pivot-table, tableau-api

I am trying to create a text table in Tableau and I want to replicate this below:

[image]

However for some reason when I have the player names as rows and distance as columns, the values are showing up as the column header (see below)

[image]

Any suggestions?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The method you have shown in your question won't work because this is not how Tableau works.
Tableau will automatically aggregate data based on the Dimensions you add to your sheet.

If you want to have a table where the distance is listed for each player, just add the following two dimensions into the Rows, in this order:

Player Name, Distance

You will still get a third column saying Abc, but this is because of how Tableau works. You can set this Abc to become shapes if it helps make your table more user friendly.